# Как разбить строку на подстроки с учетом кавычек с помощью RegEx

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Коллеги, добрый день!
Никак не могу придумать подходящий RegEx что бы разбить строку, прошу вашей помощи.

Вот строка:

```
ObjectKey="ИсторияВыбора" SettingsKey="" UserId="Авбг ДЕ ИКЛ (МНОПРСТ)" Fld46538="{""#"",784bb020-f9e0-4a39-bf27-71d2b228a981,0:bab900259066e1b911e8c53f585e588b}" Fld46539=E373A3C4CC7F9D44854C5A02EBC08E7A Fld46541=""
```

На выходе требуется получить следующее:

```
ObjectKey="ИсторияВыбора"
SettingsKey=""
UserId="Авбг ДЕ ИКЛ (МНОПРСТ)"
Fld46538="{""#"",784bb020-f9e0-4a39-bf27-71d2b228a981,0:bab900259066e1b911e8c53f585e588b}"
Fld46539=E373A3C4CC7F9D44854C5A02EBC08E7A
Fld46541=""
```

Comment: Наверное, стоит уточнить, на каком из диалектов регулярных выражений нужно решение (ли на каком из языков программирования нужно решение написать). Так же хорошо бы знать, нужна ли регулярка только для split или можно использовать replace.

Comment: Вообще это нужно разобрать в 1С там нет поддержки рег. выражений, поэтому используется dll. Насчет диалекта подойдет PHP. Если строка сможет быть разобрана здесь https://regex101.com/ то этого вполне достаточно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посторался использовать универсальные возможности, поддерживаемые в PCRE и PHP. Я предположил следующие правила:

1. Пары ключ/значение разделяются пробелом.
2. Ключ может содержать только латиницу и цифры.
3. Если значение состоит только из латиницы и цифр, оно может не заключаться в кавычки.
4. Внутри кавычек возможны пары кавычек как экранированные кавычки.

```js
const str = 'ObjectKey="ИсторияВыбора" SettingsKey="" UserId="Авбг ДЕ ИКЛ (МНОПРСТ)" Fld46538="{""#"",784bb020-f9e0-4a39-bf27-71d2b228a981,0:bab900259066e1b911e8c53f585e588b}" Fld46539=E373A3C4CC7F9D44854C5A02EBC08E7A Fld46541=""';

const re = /(?<=^| )\w+=(?:"(?:[^"]|"")*"|\w+)(?= |$)/g;

console.log(str.match(re));
```

Comment: К сожалению у меня 1С, поэтому хотелось бы сразу получить готовый результат из регулярки.

Comment: Я подправил регулярное выражение, можете протестировать при помощи https://regex101.com/

Comment: Вот это да! Спасибо огромное, все работает!